# LaTeXにおいてwrapfigureとflushleftを同時に使うとwrapfigureが効かなくなることについて

Tags: latex

LaTeXで文書の作成をしています。wrapfigure環境を用いて

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{.5\hsize}
 \begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=\hsize,bb=? ? ? ?]{??.jpg}
  \caption{???}
 \end{center}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

のように記述すると図に文章を回り込ませることができます。また、flushleft環境を用いて

```
\begin{flushleft}
本文
\end{flushleft}
```

とすることで、文章を左寄せにできます。
しかしながら、flushleft環境内でwrapfigure環境を使うと文章が回り込まなくなってしまいます。左寄せで、かつ文章を回り込ませるようにするにはどうしたらいいでしょうか。

Comment: わざわざflushleft環境を用いて左寄せにしなくても左寄せになりました。左寄せにならないと思っていたのは、\parによって改行するのを忘れていたことが原因のようで、自己解決しました。

Comment: 自己解決されているようなので，ちょっとした補足に留めますが，wrapfig パッケージを利用した回り込みは原則として「通常の段落」以外の特殊な環境が近くにあるときはあまりうまくいきません．このことは wrapfig のマニュアル（TeX Live をご利用なら `texdoc wrapfig` で開けます）の2ページにも書いてあります．どうしてもそうした環境の近くで回り込みを行いたい場合，wrapfig の代わりに picins パッケージを利用するとうまくいく場合があるようです．